# ffmpeg Unknown encoder 'libopus' centos7

Tags: ffmpeg, centos-7, opus

I am new to centos7. I installed the FFmpeg for converting mp3 files to opus (Telegram Bot). However, I tried many ways to install it, every time I got the same errors!

For example, I used [these](https://gist.github.com/freedomlang/6cac7a75f33bdb1abf0dccf3bd4fa753) commands for installing and compiling the FFmpeg. Here is my result:

> [root@ip154 nasm-2.14.02]# ffmpeg
> ffmpeg version 3.4.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
> libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
> libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
> libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
> libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
> libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
> libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
> libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
> libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
> libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
> Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
> usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

As one can see the **--enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus** is in the result.

When I run this:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -strict -2 -codec:a opus /var/www/html/0912645.ogg
```

The result is Segmentation fault!

And this code:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp3 -c:a libopus -compression_level 10 /var/www/html/hello.ogg
```

The result is Unknown encoder 'libopus'!

I don't know what to do!!!!

Comment: `--enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus` doesn't make much sense. You have probably have two versions of ffmpeg installed. The broken ffmpeg you are executing is different than the version that you get from the instructions in the link you followed (which is basically just a copy of [FFmpeg Wiki: CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos)). In some cases the shell is just remembering the location of the old version, so that is why the Wiki suggests running `hash -d ffmpeg` after installation. You can try doing that or check the path that the bot is using to run ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks. You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of `ffmpeg` installed. The broken `ffmpeg` you are executing is different than the version that you get from the instructions in the link you followed (which is basically just a copy of [FFmpeg Wiki: CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos)).

In some cases the shell is just remembering the location of the old version, so that is why the Wiki suggests running `hash -d ffmpeg` after installation. You can try doing that.

Or check the path that the bot is using to run `ffmpeg`. It might be pointing to the old, broken `ffmpeg`.